# Error on line 5, column 10 of pubspec.lock: Expected ':'. ╷ 5 │ archive:

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run `flutter pub get` it shows,

```
> flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_dropdown...                 1,922ms
Error on line 5, column 10 of pubspec.lock: Expected ':'.
  ╷
5 │   archive:
  │          ^
  ╵
Running "flutter pub get" in example...
pub get failed (65;   ╵)
```

Flutter version was 2.0.3 and updated to 2.2.3 check if that solves with the dart version to latest. Seems like versions are not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me whe I have git conflicts in my pubspec.yaml file. Specifically, I was updating my pub package and solved conficts in package but forget to solve in example pubspec.yaml conflicts. So, the pubspec.lock generation failed due to that issue.